# Why is my texture interpolated after rendering it on a surface with sampler2D

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, opentk

I'm writing a program with OpenTK in C# and I currently tried to get a texture on a group of cubes.

My problem is that when i use the given texture with 3 pixels in it and give the bitmap into my shader to a sampler2d it interpolates the colors of the texture while rendering instead of giving me 3 lines with the 3 colors on each side of each cube.

To give it into the shader i used the code similar to the one given on [this side](http://www.opentk.com/node/2865).

Here the exact code in my fragment shader:

```
#version 430 core

uniform sampler2D materialTexture;

in vec2 uvPos;

out vec4 color;

void main() 
{
    vec4 materialColor = texture2D(materialTexture, uvPos);
    color = materialColor;
}
```

Here the image used as texture shown in gimp:
[image: The 3 pixel texture]

Here the current result
[image: The result after rendering]

What would i have to do so the image would be rendered on the cubes without interpolating?
Are there maybe any flags or calls in OpenTK i can set to prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use nearest-neighbor filtering for the ***magnification*** function.

You have a 3x1 texture here, which needs to be magnified to stretch across your scene. The default magnification filter (`GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER`) in OpenGL is `GL_LINEAR`, which interpolates the four closest texels.

`GL_NEAREST` will produce the behaivor you want. Minification (when your texture resolution is too high) does not apply here, but also defaults to linear filtering.

Comment: So... how do you use that filtering mode? Obviously, I know the answer to that, but my point is that the OP didn't even know what filtering modes were. So he probably doesn't know how to set them.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Search me, the question is discussing a particular framework that obviously encapsulates texture loading. I opted only to explain the terms necessary to search for.